# Using Nativequery to delete/update records in JTA

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb, jta

I was stuck in very hard situation for a moment.

The problem is: I have to use NativeQuery to delete and/or update some DB records in a JTA context (EJB).

my JPA persistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="OzsscJPANBPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/postgres_ozssc</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>com/longz/ozssc/model/PostcodeEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.longz.ozssc.model.CustomerEntity</class>
 ......
```

If I use delete statement in this way:

```
@Override
public void remove(SmsdOutboxEntity toberemoved){
    em.createNativeQuery("Delete from outbox where \"ID\" = " + toberemoved.getId()).executeUpdate();
```

TransactionRequiredException thrown:

```
root cause

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
```

Such there is no transaction existing.

If we use transaction manually as:

```
@Override
public void remove(SmsdOutboxEntity toberemoved){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.createNativeQuery("Delete from outbox where \"ID\" = " + toberemoved.getId()).executeUpdate();
    /*em.flush();*/
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

IllegalStateException thrown:

```
root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The method public abstract javax.persistence.EntityTransaction javax.persistence.EntityManager.getTransaction() cannot be invoked in the context of a JTA EntityManager.
```

Seems I can't use transaction manually, as JTA will manage transaction their self.

So my question is: How I can use Native Query to delete/update records in a JTA managed context?

Please advise.

Comment: The first thing you should look into is \"ID\" in your query. Why did you put a column name in quotation marks? Have you tried to run this query against you DB directly? Did it do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The second thing:  the code you submitted is insufficient. Provide code for your entity and EJB. Code you submitted potentially may have other problems but it is hard to say based on the code you provided.

Comment: The third thing:  I would strongly advise you reconsider your approach of deleting entities. It will lead you to troubles. Unless you know exactly what you are doing and what are the consequences of that you should delete using remove method of your entity manager. Same for update.

Comment: I used \"ID\" in my query, because my database table is case sensitive as other application developed by C++ will access that table too.

Comment: Most work been done by my C++ application. My Java Application only used to handle exception records and monitoring C++ application working status. So delete logic is the only logic need to be fulfil in Java.

Answer (score 0):

For JTA the transaction is provided by the container and you should not create it by yourself. To obtain the transaction in JTA, you have to access it as a resource:

```
@Resource public UserTransaction utx;
@Resource public EntityManagerFactory factory;

@Override
public void remove(SmsdOutboxEntity toberemoved){
   EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
try {
   em.createNativeQuery("Delete from outbox where \"ID\" = " + toberemoved.getId()).executeUpdate();
   utx.commit();

catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (utx != null) utx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
finally {
    em.close();
}
```

If you want to omit the part where you have commit/rollback the transaction by yourself, you need to have your transaction managed by some container like EJB3. For that you can use stateless/stateful ejb beans.

**UPDATE:**

For WebLogic, try to use its user [weblogic.transaction.UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24391/weblogic/transaction/UserTransaction.html) instead of [javax.transaction.UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html). As the doc says:

> This interface defines WebLogic-specific extensions to
>   javax.transaction.UserTransaction.

Comment: I will test your advice and reply soon.

Comment: I tested this update, it not work in my situation, Weblogic 12C rejected deploy a user defined transaction which conflict with Weblogic container. I will need some more research to see what we can do. if you have better idea, please let me know. Appreciated...